# django-haystack - No module named search_sites

Tags: django-haystack

I download `django-haystack-1.1.0.tar.gz`, unzip it, then copy `haystack` directory, which is in it, to my `apps` directory and add `haystack` to my `INSTALLED_APPS` (also add whoosh, because i copy it too), but when i restart server i get 500 internal error. Then i delete, for experiment, `handle_registrations()` from `haystack.__init__` and site start working, but when i try search by haystack i get `No fields were found in any search_indexes. Please correct this before attempting to search.` In settings.py i have also:

```
HAYSTACK_SITECONF = 'search_sites'  
HAYSTACK_SEARCH_ENGINE = 'whoosh'  
HAYSTACK_WHOOSH_PATH = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'mysite_search_sites')
```

Then i undelete `handle_registrations()`, delete haystack from `INSTALLED_APPS` and restart server and now i am getting `No module named search_sites`.
Also `import haystack` and `haystack.__version__` works but `haystack.management.commands` didn't.
Could someone help me with this, please?

**EDIT**
My traceback:

```
/lib/python2.7/django/core/handlers/base.py in get_response
                        response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs) ...
▶ Local vars
/myproject/apps/djangobb_forum/util.py in wrapper
            output = function(request, *args, **kwargs)
 ...
▶ Local vars
/myproject/apps/djangobb_forum/util.py in wrapper
            result = func(request, *args, **kwargs)
 ...
▶ Local vars
/myproject/apps/djangobb_forum/views.py in search
                for post in posts:
 ...
▶ Local vars
/myproject/apps/haystack/query.py in _manual_iter
            if not self._fill_cache(current_position, current_position + ITERATOR_LOAD_PER_QUERY):
 ...
▶ Local vars
/myproject/apps/haystack/query.py in _fill_cache
        results = self.query.get_results()
 ...
▶ Local vars
/myproject/apps/haystack/backends/__init__.py in get_results
                self.run()
 ...
▶ Local vars
/myproject/apps/haystack/backends/__init__.py in run
        results = self.backend.search(final_query, **kwargs)
 ...
▶ Local vars
/myproject/apps/haystack/backends/__init__.py in wrapper
            return func(obj, query_string, *args, **kwargs)
 ...
▶ Local vars
/myproject/apps/haystack/backends/whoosh_backend.py in search
            self.setup()
 ...
▶ Local vars
/myproject/apps/haystack/backends/whoosh_backend.py in setup
        self.content_field_name, self.schema = self.build_schema(self.site.all_searchfields())
 ...
▶ Local vars
/myproject/apps/haystack/backends/whoosh_backend.py in build_schema
            raise SearchBackendError("No fields were found in any search_indexes. Please correct this before attempting to search.")
 ...
▶ Local vars
```

Answer (score 2):

From the install steps you've listed it sounds like you're missing a few steps.

Definitely revisit the [Haystack setup instructions](http://docs.haystacksearch.org/dev/tutorial.html) with a particular eye to looking at the Create a Search Site and Creating Indexes sections.

The long and short is you seem to be missing an indexes file. Haystack registers a bunch of stuff from your indexes when it is first included, so that explains why you're getting errors from `haystack.__init__`

Add a file called 'search_indexes.py' to your application directory. This file contains a list of the indexes you want to generate for different models. A simple example would be:

```
from haystack.indexes import *
from haystack import site
from myapp.models import MyModel

class MyModelIndex(SearchIndex):
    text = CharField(document=True, use_template=True)

    def prepare(self, obj):
        self.prepared_data = super(MyModelIndex, self).prepare(obj)
        self.prepared_data['text'] = obj.my_field

site.register(MyModel, MyModelIndex)
```

This will add a free text search field called 'text' to your index. When you search for free text without a field to search specified, haystack will search this field by default. The property `my_field` from the model `MyModel` is added to this text field and is made searchable. This could, for example, be the name of the model or some appropriate text field. The example is a little naive, but it will do for now to help you get something up and running, and you can then read up a bit and expand it.

The call `site.register` registers this index against the model `MyModel` so haystack can discover it.

You'll also need a file called `search_sites.py` (Name as per your settings) in your project directory to point to the index files you've just made. Adding the following will make it look through your apps and auto-discover any indexes you've registered.

```
import haystack
haystack.autodiscover()
```

Comment: i have `search_indexes` file but it didn't help. I go to search in haystack docs if i missed something.

Comment: Could you turn on debugging (DEBUG=True in settings.py) and give us the specific error that you're getting at the 500, as well as any relevant info of the view it's occurring in? Also, where are you seeing the 'No fields were found' error?

Comment: error 500 is in DEBUG=True, and that is strange for me, but i edit my question and add my traceback

Answer (score 2):

You need to create **search_sites.py** in ur **project root** dir according to ur settings.py and add

```
import haystack
haystack.autodiscover()
```

This will fix the **"No module named search_sites"** error
And this is the [LatestDocs](http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/v1.2.7/tutorial.html) for Django-Haystack Configurations